# How to access the raw soap envelope request using soap npm

Tags: javascript, npm, soap

I'm using npm soap to create a soap webserver and I need to know if it's possible to get the raw soap envelope inside my method.

This example is from

```
var myService = {
      MyService: {
          MyPort: {
              reallyDetailedFunction: function(args, cb, headers, req) {
                   // how to get the raw soap envelope here ????
              }
          }
      }
  };

  var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8');

  //express server example
  var app = express();
  app.listen(8001, function(){
      soap.listen(app, '/wsdl', myService, xml, function(){
        console.log('server initialized');
      });
  });
```

I am using Postman as a client and I need to have access to the raw envelope:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://x.y.z.x.y.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:reallyDetailedFunction xsi:type="ns1:reallyDetailedFunction">
        <request xsi:type="ns1:reallyDetailedFunctionRequest">
            <countryCode>us</countryCode>
            <languageCode>en</languageCode>
            ....
    </ns1:reallyDetailedFunction>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

inside inside the `reallyDetailedFuncion` above.

I never worked with soap webserver so I'm kind of lost here. Maybe there is a better option than soap npm.